# Building an Objective-C framework: Unable to find header file at path when accessing module from Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

**Intro**

I'm looking to create an Objective-C framework inside XCode to be used by our Swift Application, but am running into an issue where the header files can not be found at their path when building  and then importing the module (Swift needs a module as far as I know) defined by the framework target, but said path is fine when simply compiling the framework.

**Example**

For example: In my Objective-C Framework I have two classes. Class A and class B. A is a superclass of B, so naturally I included A's header file within B's header in order to declare their relationship, like so:

```
//Inside file: ClassA.h_________________

@interface ClassA : NSObject

   //Some implementation

@end

//Inside file: ClassB.h ________________

#include "src/models/ClassA.h"
@interface ClassB: ClassA

//Some implementation

@end
```

Now everything's looking great and runs as expected when running the target which solely defines my framework. Upon attempting import the module from within our Swift application, the aforementioned `#include "src/models/ClassA.h"` statement fails to be resolved.
On a side note: My Swift application uses another similar, albeit smaller framework without a folder structure.

**Current Status**

Steps I've taken to ensure the header "should" be found:

1. My Swift application target depends on the Objective-C framework.
2. My Framework is set to define a module inside it's build settings.
3. The header files of both ClassA and ClassB are marked as public under XCode's Build Phases tab.
4. Inside my frameworks umbrella header, I've imported the headers of both ClassA and ClassB like so:

```
//Inside header file called MyFramework.h
#import <MyFramework/ClassA.h>
#import <MyFramework/ClassB.h>
```

Now I realize that Swift accessing the module has access to ClassA and ClassB as their are lying directly inside the Headers folder produced by the framework/module, which is why the import statements in the umbrella header are no longer the file path these files normally have within my project.
But as soon as my Swift application goes to parse the header of ClassB and reads the include statement to include ClassA.h an error is thrown that the header file can not be found.

**Question**

How can I make this work, or at least make use of ClassA and ClassB from within my Swift Application accessing this framework module?

By the way, I need the folder paths because I have multiple header files with the name "ClassA" and "ClassB" (lets call them that for this example).

Bit more info in case helpful: It's a truly large java framework with some thousands of files translated into Objective-C by making use of "j2objc". As such some of the files share the same name.

Comment: What happens if you change the `#import` in `ClassB.h` to `#import <MyFramework/ClassA.h>`?

Comment: @sbooth Then it will find the file. However this only works as long as no files share the same name of say "ClassA.h", which they do and is the reason for me accessing them via path.